# How to loop through variables w/ trend trading system

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I built a simple moving average trading system like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def trendfunc(f1,fastnum,slownum):
    f1['Change'] = f1['Close'].pct_change()
    f1['Fast'] = f1['Close'].rolling(window=fastnum,center=False).mean() 
    f1['Slow'] = f1['Close'].rolling(window=slownum,center=False).mean() 
    f1['Trend'] = f1['Fast'] - f1['Slow'] 
    f1['Position'] = np.where(f1['Trend'].shift(2)>0,1,0) 
    f1['Result'] = f1['Position']*f1['Change']
    f1 = f1.dropna()
    f1['MktVAMI'] = f1['Change']+1
    f1['MktVAMI'].iloc[0] = 1000
    f1['MktVAMI'] = f1['MktVAMI'].cumprod()
    f1['MktHi'] = f1['MktVAMI'].cummax()
    f1['MktDD'] = (f1['MktVAMI']/f1['MktHi'])-1
    f1['MktMaxDD'] = f1['MktDD'].cummin()
    f1['SysVAMI'] = f1['Result']+1
    f1['SysVAMI'].iloc[0] = 1000
    f1['SysVAMI'] = f1['SysVAMI'].cumprod()
    f1['SysHi'] = f1['SysVAMI'].cummax()
    f1['SysDD'] = (f1['SysVAMI']/f1['SysHi'])-1
    f1['SysMaxDD'] = f1['SysDD'].cummin()
    keep = ['Date','MktVAMI','MktMaxDD','SysVAMI','SysMaxDD']
    f2 = f1[keep].tail(1)
    return f2

tkrs = ['spy']

for tkr in tkrs:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(f'C:\\Path\\To\\Date\\{tkr}.csv')
    FastMA = 50
    SlowMA = 200
    AA = trendfunc(df1,FastMA,SlowMA)
```

In the code above, I use one "fast" moving average (FastMA = 50) and one "slow" moving average (SlowMA = 200). I'd like to be able to loop through several possible values for both FastMA and SlowMA.

So, I might want to use:

FastMA = [10,20,30]
FastMA = [100,200,300]

Where I end up with 9 possible combination each of which is fed to the "trendfunc" function.

I'd also like to append each result to a dataframe with the values used for the respective variables so I could then export that dataframe and compare results.

My loop skills aren't very strong when it comes to multi level nesting and appending to a dataframe hence this post. Please help. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested loops to iterate through all the combinations and call your function for each combo. Then you can store the results in the dataframe and append the values of `FastMA` and `SlowMA` to it also.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tkrs = ['spy']

results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['FastMA', 'SlowMA', 'MktVAMI', 'MktMaxDD', 'SysVAMI', 'SysMaxDD'])

fast_ma_list = [10, 20, 30]
slow_ma_list = [100, 200, 300]

for fast_ma in fast_ma_list:
    for slow_ma in slow_ma_list:
        for tkr in tkrs:
            df1 = pd.read_csv(f'C:\\Path\\To\\Date\\{tkr}.csv')
            AA = trendfunc(df1, fast_ma, slow_ma)
            AA['FastMA'] = fast_ma
            AA['SlowMA'] = slow_ma
            results = results.append(AA, ignore_index=True)

print(results) # Do whatever with results
```

The nested loops are used to iterate through all the possible combinations of `FastMA` and `SlowMA`. For each combination, the `trendfunc()` is called and the output is stored in the `AA` dataframe. The values of `FastMA` and `SlowMA` are then appended to the `AA` dataframe, and the `AA` df is then appended to the `results` df.

Comment: This works, thanks. It does however throw a whole lot of warnings. "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" & "Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead" Any thoughts?

Comment: @GC123 those warnings are usually related to changed indexing in pandas. When you use chained indexing like `f1['Change'] = f1['Close'].pct_change()` or `f1= f1.dropna()`, pandas creates a temp copy of the data and assigns the value to that copy which can lead to the original data not being modified as intended.

You can use the `.loc` accessor to perform assignment operations in a single step :)